# How does one merge best the most inner array items of a two dimensional array into a flat one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, merge

I have a two dimension array like this

```
[
  [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }],
  [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { b: 3 }],
  [{ c: 1 }, { c: 2 }, { c: 3 }]
]
```

Is there any way to merge it as

```
[
  [{ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 }],
  [{ a: 2, b: 2, c: 2 }],
  [{ a: 3, b: 3, c: 3 }]
]
```

Comment: do you have some code, you tried? what does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All proposed approaches until now use a combination of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). In addition every approach for creating the merged objects uses either [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or the [spread syntax for/within object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) or both.

These are just tools. But one needs to have a basic understanding of the available tools and how they work in order to come up with an algorithm.

One, of cause could solve the problem via `for`/`while` based loops but it would not contribute to readability.

Thus, dear OP, read yourself not just through the documentation of e.g. [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object); but maybe start from there.

```js
function zipAndMergeWithBoundArray(obj, idx) {
  return this.reduce(
    (assignee, vector) => Object.assign(assignee, vector[idx]),
    { ...obj } // shallow copy in order to not mutate the original 
  );
}

const sampleArray = [
  [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }], // take the first row/vector ...

  [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { b: 3 }], // ... and zip&merge it
  [{ c: 1 }, { c: 2 }, { c: 3 }], // ... with the other
  [{ d: 1 }, { d: 2 }, { d: 3 }], // ... rows/vectors
  [{ e: 1 }, { e: 2 }, { e: 3 }]  // ... of the table/matrix rest.
];

console.log(
  //first vector                                // table/matrix rest
  sampleArray[0].map(zipAndMergeWithBoundArray, sampleArray.slice(1))
);

// remains not mutated...
console.log(sampleArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do 2 steps: first transpose the array, then merge each element

```js
const input = [
  [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }],
  [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { b: 3 }],
  [{ c: 1 }, { c: 2 }, { c: 3 }]
]

const transpose = array =>
  array[0].map((a, i) => array.map(b => b[i]))

const mergeAll = arrOfObj =>
  arrOfObj.reduce((acc, el) => Object.assign(acc, el), {})

const res = transpose(input).map(mergeAll)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the outer array and map the inner array with the objects at the same index of the result array.

```js
const 
    data = [[{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }], [{ b: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { b: 3 }], [{ c: 1 }, { c: 2 }, { c: 3 }]],
    result = data.reduce(
        (target, objects) => objects.map((object, index) => ({ ...target[index], ...object })),
        []
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```